# Using proxy like fiddler with fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, fiddler, fetch-api

How can I set a proxy using Fetch API.
I'm developing a node.js application and I'd like to have a look at the response body of an HTTPS response. I'm using this npm package that uses node http inside:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch

I tried to set the env variables like:

```
set https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
set http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

but it seems to work only with request NPM node module.

I always get the following message:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888
(node:30044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): FetchError: request to https://www.index.hu failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
```

Comment: I'd suggest opening a bug with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), as the variable should affect all node modules.

Comment: @Bergi: it has been implemented in node-fetch, see https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch#options

Comment: @serv-inc Oh, right, that's about the proxy, I thought the problem would be with `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED`

Answer (score 5):

[@jimliang](https://github.com/jimliang) [has posted a solution for `node-fetch`](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/79#issuecomment-184594701). He

> used https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent

```
fetch('https://www.google.com',{ agent:new HttpsProxyAgent('http://127.0.0.1:8580')})
.then(function(res){
    //...
})
```