# node-fetch responding with 503 where request responding with 200 behind proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, request, fetch

Below I have two http requests, one made with `request` and the other being made with `isomorphic-fetch` (`node-fetch`). For some reason the request with `request` works, however `node-fetch` is responding back with an error code `503`. Is there anything I am missing from the fetch version?

```
const URL = require('url')
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch')
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent')
const request = require('request');

const url = process.env.URL
const proxy = process.env.PROXY

const requestPromise = function (url, options) {
    if (/^\/\//.test(url)) {
    url = 'https:' + url;
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return request.call(this, url, options, function (err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
            }

            res.ok = true;
            res.json = function () {
            return JSON.parse(res.body);
            }
            return resolve(res);
        });
    });
};

function getProxy (url) {
    const parsedProxyURL = URL.parse(url);
    parsedProxyURL.secureProxy = parsedProxyURL.protocol === 'https:';
    return parsedProxyURL
}

requestPromise(url, {
    agent:new HttpsProxyAgent(getProxy(proxy))
})
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log)


fetch(url, {
    agent:new HttpsProxyAgent(getProxy(proxy))
})
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log)
```

Comment: Newer Nodejs should have native fetch,  isomorphic is using node-fetch: https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/blob/master/package.json#L22 and that should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572328/1641941 Did you try the url as string as in the answer or here? https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/79

Comment: @HMR as you can see above I am doing pretty much what you've shown, rather then passing a string to `HttpsProxyAgent` you can provide options. There is still a difference between `request` and `node-fetch` that is defaulted in `request` that makes it work, and not present in `node-fetch`.

Answer (score 2):

The `request` module seems to be setting one header automatically, the `host` that `fetch` module is not. by making this change it works.

```
const URL = require('url')
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch')
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent')
const request = require('request')

function getProxy (url) {
    const parsedProxyURL = URL.parse(url)
    parsedProxyURL.secureProxy = parsedProxyURL.protocol === 'https:'
    return parsedProxyURL
}

const url = process.env.URL
const proxy = process.env.PROXY

fetch(url, {
    headers: {host: URL.parse(url).host},
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(getProxy(proxy))
})
    .then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(console.log)
```